# unable to update value in mysql database using php

Tags: php, mysql

I am not able to update MySQL table using PHP. How can I do that?

I have tried by changing the order of double quotes.

```php
$name=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["steel"]);
$db->execute("UPDATE order SET need=$name WHERE raw-id='1'");
```

It should store `$name` in the database.

Comment: What's happening when you execute the code you posted? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: ***Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).*** [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***. Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: No I am not getting any errors.

Comment: I am using older version of php

Comment: _“No I am not getting any errors”_ - you’re not _asking_ for any, which is what you usually have to when working with MySQL databases in PHP. So please go inform yourself how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wrap your $name with single quote, because you are trying to pass a string into the SQL

```
$db->execute("UPDATE order SET need='$name' WHERE `raw-id`='1'");
```

Answer (score 1):

You should wrap your `{$name}` with single quote and bracket to , because need row is  a string into the SQL

```
$db->execute("UPDATE order SET need='{$name}' WHERE `raw-id`='1'");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your column name in back-ticks because it has a dash in it, e.g:

```php
$db->execute("UPDATE order SET need = '$name' WHERE `raw-id` = 1");
```

Comment: As DM Buzz suggested in another answer, have you tried wrapping `$name` in single quotes also? It's quite hard to help if you have no errors.

Answer (score 0):

By referring to the [manual](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php) I think you should first prepare your
query and then use execute() method. Something like this:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO myCity (Name, CountryCode, District) VALUES (?,?,?)";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
```